# Why doesn't this script collect all gmails?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google app script that collects information about Gmail messages and then pastes it into a google sheet.  Trouble is it doesn't get ALL of the messages.  It only picks up the first one of each thread.  I feel like I am missing something to loop through each thread? Any suggestions?

```
    function getMail(){
 var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
 var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet3");    

 var start = 0;
 var max = 99;
 var count =0;
 var row = mysheet.getLastRow()+1
 var maxDate = mysheet.getRange("B1").getValue()
 while(count < 4) 
 {

   var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start , max);
   var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
   var froms = [];
    messages.get
      for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
      {

        var msgDate = messages[i][0].getDate();
        if(msgDate>maxDate){
          froms.push([messages[i][0].getDate(),messages[i][0].getFrom(),messages[i][0].getSubject(),messages[i][0].getPlainBody()]);
        }
      }

   if(froms.length>0){
     mysheet.insertRows(2, froms.length)
     mysheet.getRange(2,1,froms.length,4).setValues(froms);
   }
   start =  start + 100;
    count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current script is only grabbing `messages[i][0]`, the first message in that group for the thread. Instead you need to loop through all of the messages using two for loops, as you can see in the script below I use `messages[i][j]`.

```
function getMail() {
  var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var mySheet = mySpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet3");    

  var start = 0;
  var max = 99;
  var count = 0;
  var maxDate = mySheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

  while(count < 4) {
    var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, max);
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
    var froms = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
      var msgDate = messages[i][j].getDate();
        if(msgDate > maxDate) {
          froms.push([msgDate,messages[i][j].getFrom(),messages[i][j].getSubject(),messages[i][j].getPlainBody()]);
        }
      }
    }
    if(froms.length > 0) {
      mySheet.insertRows(2, froms.length);
      mySheet.getRange(2, 1, froms.length, 4).setValues(froms);
    }
    start =  start + 100;
    count++;
  }
}
```

Notable changes:

- removed `var rows` because it wasn't used anywhere in the script.
- changed first for loop to run for `messages.length` rather than
  threads.
- added another for loop to loop through every message in
  `messages[i]`.
- you were getting `messages[i][0].getDate()` twice, so I just used the variable already defined for adding to the array.
- minor grammatical/spacing changes for consistency across script.

Comment: You appear to have also deleted
        `messages.get`
Any reason for that?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I forgot to add that to the list. You're already getting the messages in `var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);` so there's no reason to do it again.

Comment: I assumed that was the case.  But here's what's weird: when I run the script as you modified, It returns a little under 400 emails.  When I put the `messages.get` back in, it returns 747 messages, which is the number I am looking for.  (Thanks LOADS for your help BTW)